# Insert pictures HERE

Tags: graphics, floats

I'm required to insert picture right in place. So I used `[H]` to `figure`. Unfortunately I have a lot of figures, and some mechanisms gets overloaded — and I get all figures stucked in the end of the section (even if I `clearpage` in the end of each section).

So I made it all as a minipage:

```
\def\Figure#1 {
  \vspace{2mm}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    #1
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace{2mm}
}
```

Example usage:

```
\Figure{
  \centering
  \input{img/DiracComb02_reduced.pgf} % or \includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{img/Au}
  \captionof{figure}[Short caption for list of figures]{Caption\label{fig:DiracComb02_reduced}}
}
```

but this seems to be vertically justifying text:

[image]

If I insert `clearpage` at the beginning of the `Figure` — the problem is solved, but I get every picture starts at the top of the page — no matter if it fits in to the previous.

What would You do?

Comment: Try `\raggedbottom`.

Comment: If you use `H` the figures do not move and `\clearpage` has no effect (other than to force a page break). Using `H` makes large spaces inevitable as it disables the latex float mechanism which is designed to avoid such spaces.

Comment: Formal figures with numbered captions are not always appropriate.  Maybe you don't need to put your pictures into floating figure environments?  A technique I sometimes use is just to put my pictures directly into a paragraph like displayed maths: `\[\includegraphics{picture}\]` this can work very well in many situations.  Obviously if your pictures are very large compared to your page size you may get page break issues, but dealing with them might be easier than what you are trying to do with minipages.

Comment: In the particular example you have given you could also consider redrawing the graph with a smaller vertical scale, then it might fit better.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I know, but I'm required to leave the spaces, and place the figure right there. Personally I think it is stupid. Using `H` places all my figures in the end of the section.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: please make it an answer, so I can accept it. The command `\raggedbottom` prevents LaTeX from adding vertical white space in strange places on pages that it cannot fill properly. Seem to be wokring fine.

Comment: `H` just locally redefines figure to be a vbox (minipage) so they never move, if the figures move when you have `H` you must have some local definition rather than the one from here.sty/float.sty (impossible to tell as no working example supplied)